# elif statements wont print if True

Tags: python, if-statement, printing

I'm making an app that will tell you what generation you belong to but can't get the elifs to print just the if statement.

```
Age = input('What year where you born? ')

if int(Age) >= 2001:
    print("Generation Z/Boomlets")
elif int(Age) == range(1981, 2000):
    print("Generation Y/Millennium")
elif int(Age) == range(1965, 1980):
    print("Generation X")
elif int(Age) == range(1946, 1964):
    print("Baby Boomers")
elif int(Age) == range(1927, 1945):
    print("Mature / Silents")
elif int(Age) == range(1901, 1926):
    print("GI Generation")
```

Comment: Why would `int` be equal to `range`? you need to check if `age` is `in` the range.

Comment: well it wont accept anything else other than == but i would like the input to be checked to see if it matches the range and then print if it does

Comment: Here you can read more about: [`range` in Python](https://realpython.com/python-range/).

Comment: + see [PEP 8 – Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/). It describes the conventions for formatting your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your input to `int` right at the beginning (and won't need to do it in every if):

```py
age = int(input('What year where you born? '))
```

Replace your `==` signs with `in`.

```py
elif age in range(1981, 2000):
    ...
```

- there is a convention in Python: variable names should start with a smaller-case letter.

Comment: Also added int to the beginning so wouldn't have to do it every single line thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### Integer can't be equal to `range()`. So, you've to check if the given year is `in` the `range()`

```py
Age = input('What year where you born? ')

if int(Age) >= 2001:
    print("Generation Z/Boomlets")
elif int(Age) in range(1981, 2000):
    print("Generation Y/Millennium")
elif int(Age) in range(1965, 1980):
    print("Generation X")
elif int(Age) in range(1946, 1964):
    print("Baby Boomers")
elif int(Age) in range(1927, 1945):
    print("Mature / Silents")
elif int(Age) in range(1901, 1926):
    print("GI Generation")
```

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you have used "==  range()", do any one of the below:

1. Replace "==" with "in".
2. int(Age) >= 1981 and int(Age)<2000.

**P.S:**

```
Age = input('What year where you born? ')
```

change the above code to the below one so that you don't need to write int(Age) everywhere:

```
Age = int(input('What year where you born? '))
```

Comment: `int(Age) >= 1981 and int(Age)<2000` can be written as `1981 <= int(Age) < 2000`